# Setting Network settings from Python/Django on a Linux/Ubuntu machine

Tags: python, django, networking, ubuntu, ip

I'm working on a simple web interface for an embedded computer. The computer will ship with a static default ip that will then need to be updated by the install tech who may not be tech/linux savvy.

Basicly I need to change the following system settings from a Django app.

1. IP Addres
2. Subnet
3. Default Gateway
4. DNS Servers 1&2

I realize that I can could just overwrite the config files in linux but I was wondering if there is a more "Python" way of doing it.

Comment: Whether you implement a python script, a shell script, etc. all of them have to end up affecting the Linux system configuration.  To make these settings "static", configuration files must be updated.  That said, you're not looking for a solution "instead of" configuration files, but to wrap/obfusctate manipulation of configuration files.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Have a look at pynetlinux on Github:

https://github.com/rlisagor/pynetlinux

It is a good starting point and you can add the remaining functionality yourself quite easily I would imagine.

Comment: Rockin sauce! Thanks a ton! I'll have a look and report back, but at first glance it looks to be the answer!