# Is there a python module for managing interfaces on Ubuntu?

Tags: python, networking, ubuntu

I did a bit of searching and I couldn't find anything that fit my needs. I am preferably looking for a python module which can:

- Change the mac of my interface
- Change the IP of my interface
- Add an IP to the interface
- Change the IP of the interface (static)

Does anybody know if there is something that exists for this? I am on Ubuntu.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5650965/setting-network-settings-from-python-django-on-a-linux-ubuntu-machine
this is similar question to link..

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Why is there any need for a Python module???
All can be done from the command line!

E.g. take a look at:https://help.ubuntu.com/10.04/serverguide/network-configuration.html

Get the commands needed and execute them from Python.

Comment: This is a completely unhelpful response. There are various distribution specific ways of managing persistent and transient network interface/address state. Shelling out to execute command line tools is messy and often doesn't provide stable programmatic interfaces

Answer (score 2):

[python-netifaces](https://packages.debian.org/sid/python-netifaces) can dump information about interfaces on linux, OSX and a few other platforms.

[pynetlinux](https://github.com/rlisagor/pynetlinux) appears to provide some nice linux bindings around the relevant ioctls to change current run time state, but hasn't seen any real activity in over 6 months.

But, there doesn't appear any obvious projects which support a nice clean pythonic interface for manipulating /etc/network/... on Debian based distributions which presumably would be what you'd want/need to do to get decent persistent configuration changes.